# ListView becomes null in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to define a listview with a corresponding Adapter to add string to the listview. Howevewr, my listview comes as being null. The code is as below:-

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {
....
....
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cat_vacancies);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

....

}
}
```

What have I done wrong at this point?

my fragment xml is as follows( I have only added the relevant portions which I think may help in diagnosing the problem)

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cat_vacancies">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S. This is, as far as I know, a silly mistake, but I have not yet completely grasped android completely, so excuse my problems.

Comment: in `onCreateView()` you have to inflate the layout which has listview in it.

Comment: check this it may help you to solve your problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778291/listview-returning-null-using-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.[layout id], container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat_vacancies);
retrun view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try whit that way

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourFragmentXml, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat_vacancies);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

....

}
```

Comment: How is this different from @Surya Prakash Kushawah answer, don't post same answers.

Comment: same time post nothing difference in both

Comment: @AkshayBhat We are try to give answers we at time on post i did not know some one is also giving same answers. So sorry if i have give same answers.